# A weird CREATE EXTENSION WITH error of postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema

I init app_auth database, create extension pgcrypto with app_auth schema, but tests show i create the extension into the public schema, why?

```
-- init
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS app_auth CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA app_auth;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto WITH SCHEMA app_auth;

-- test1: without schema
SET search_path = app_auth;
SELECT gen_random_bytes(10); -- "ERROR: function gen_random_bytes(integer) does not exist"

-- test2: with schema app_auth
SET search_path = app_auth;
SELECT app_auth.gen_random_bytes(10); -- "ERROR: function gen_random_bytes(integer) does not exist"

-- test3: with schema public
SET search_path = app_auth;
SELECT public.gen_random_bytes(10); -- "it works"
```

Comment: PostgreSQL version 10.0 by elephantsql

Comment: Looks like the extension already existed. Try `\dx` with psql.

Comment: Thanks, you are right~, I've found the extension already existed in public, is there a safe way to init the database schema `app_auth` to make the test 

    `SELECT app_auth.gen_random_bytes(10);`

always pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [move the extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterextension.html) to a different schema:

```
alter extension pgcrypto set schema app_auth;
```

---

> is there a safe way to init the database schema app_auth to make the test ... pass?

Another option is to first drop the extension

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS app_auth CASCADE;
DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS pgcrypto;
CREATE SCHEMA app_auth;
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto WITH SCHEMA app_auth;
```